# How do I reset the numbers after calculating the Total

Tags: javascript, html, css

How will I clear the total after the first calculation?
I want it to reset if I add a new item after the first calculation. Right now it's adding it to the previous one.
For example, for the first calculation (item1 + item2) = total
if I add another item, it becomes (item1 + item 2) + (item1 + item2 + item3) = total

What I want is for it to reset and calculate the new total with the new item added.

```js
 var count = 0;
    var tax = 0.05;
    var taxFeild = document.getElementById("Tax");
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementById("checkBoxes");
    var checks=document.querySelectorAll('.items');
    var ItemTotal=document.getElementById('ItemTotal');
    var Total=document.getElementById('TotalWithTax');
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");


function Calculate()
      {
       
       for(var i =0 ;i< checks.length;i++)
         {
           if(checks[i].checked)
             {
               count+=parseFloat(checks[i].value);
             }
         }
        ItemTotal.textContent += count;
        taxFeild.textContent += (parseFloat(tax*count).toFixed(2));
        Total.textContent += ((tax*count) + count).toFixed(2);
      }

        btn.addEventListener('click',Calculate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 
</head>
<body>

<h2 class="first-heading">Assignment 1</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      <div id="checkBoxes">
            <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'>Fried Chicken ($7.99)<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='9.99'> Fried Halibut ($9.99)<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'> Hamburger ($7.99)<br>  
            <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='12.99'> Grilled salmon($12.99)<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='5.99'> Side salad ($5.99)<br>       
            <button id="btn">Calculate</button>  
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" >
         
        <div id="Sums">
                <p id="ItemTotal"> Item Total: </p>
                <p id="Tax"> Tax: </p>
                <p id="TotalWithTax">Total with Tax: </p>      
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="java.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use onblur on your calculator button to reset all your calculations. `<button id="btn" onblur="createAResetFunction()">Calculates</button>`

Comment: The `+=` in `Total.textContent += ((tax*count) + count).toFixed(2);` should just be an `=`. It's concatenating the last result with the new result.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Problem with just `=` is that that element has other content in it on pageload, so if you just overwrite it, it'll be lost

Comment: @CertainPerformance Shame on me for visually "solving" this while eating dinner.

Comment: How do you know the 'calculate' button was not pressed prematurely? Like, oops, I forgot to check an item (I just did!). That's why cashregisters have a 'subtotal' and a 'total' button. I suggest you add a 'reset' button...

Answer (score 3):

You should:

- Declare the `count` variable *inside* the `Calculate` function, so that it starts from 0 every time the button is clicked
- Instead of `+=`ing to the `ItemTotal`, `TotalWithTax`, etc fields, create an *inner* element that you assign to the text to instead. So, for example, instead of

```
<p id="ItemTotal"> Item Total: </p>
```

use:

```
<p> Item Total: <span id="ItemTotal"></span></p>
```

This way, whenever the button is clicked, you can simply assign to the `ItemTotal`, overwriting whatever was there previously.

```js
var tax = 0.05;
var taxFeild = document.getElementById("Tax");
var checkBoxes = document.getElementById("checkBoxes");
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
var ItemTotal = document.getElementById('ItemTotal');
var Total = document.getElementById('TotalWithTax');
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");


function Calculate() {
  let count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked) {
      count += parseFloat(checks[i].value);
    }
  }
  ItemTotal.textContent = count;
  taxFeild.textContent = (parseFloat(tax * count).toFixed(2));
  Total.textContent = ((tax * count) + count).toFixed(2);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', Calculate);
```

```html
<h2 class="first-heading">Assignment 1</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="checkBoxes">
      <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'>Fried Chicken ($7.99)<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='9.99'> Fried Halibut ($9.99)<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'> Hamburger ($7.99)<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='12.99'> Grilled salmon($12.99)<br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='5.99'> Side salad ($5.99)<br>
      <button id="btn">Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">

    <div id="Sums">
      <p> Item Total: <span id="ItemTotal"></span></p>
      <p> Tax: <span id="Tax"></span></p>
      <p>Total with Tax: <span id="TotalWithTax"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might also consider surrounding the `input`s with `<label>`s, to make them more clickable:

```js
var taxRate = 0.05;

var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
var subtotalSpan = document.getElementById('ItemTotal');
var taxSpan = document.getElementById("Tax");
var totalSpan = document.getElementById('TotalWithTax');

function Calculate() {
  let subtotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    if (checks[i].checked) {
      subtotal += parseFloat(checks[i].value);
    }
  }
  const tax = taxRate * subtotal;
  const total = tax + subtotal;
  
  subtotalSpan.textContent = subtotal;
  taxSpan.textContent = tax.toFixed(2);
  totalSpan.textContent = total.toFixed(2);
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', Calculate);
```

```css
#checkBoxes > label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="first-heading">Assignment 1</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="checkBoxes">
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'>Fried Chicken ($7.99)</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="items" value='9.99'> Fried Halibut ($9.99)</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'> Hamburger ($7.99)</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="items" value='12.99'> Grilled salmon($12.99)</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="items" value='5.99'> Side salad ($5.99)</label><br>
      <button id="btn">Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div id="Sums">
      <p> Item Total: <span id="ItemTotal"></span></p>
      <p> Tax: <span id="Tax"></span></p>
      <p>Total with Tax: <span id="TotalWithTax"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onblur event on your calculator button. The onblur event occurs when you click off of an object. After a user clicks the "calculate" button, when they click anywhere else, the onblur function will call.

You can find out more about the onblur event at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

W3Schools has a lot of easy to learn information. Here are other events which may prove to be useful in the future (or for expanding this project): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

A simple reset function can reset your counter and your paragraph tags.

```js
var count = 0;
var tax = 0.05;
var taxFeild = document.getElementById("Tax");
var checkBoxes = document.getElementById("checkBoxes");
var checks=document.querySelectorAll('.items');
var ItemTotal=document.getElementById('ItemTotal');
var Total=document.getElementById('TotalWithTax');
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// RESET YOUR CALCULATOR FIELDS & COUNT
function resetCalc(){
 count = 0; 
 ItemTotal.textContent = "Item Total: ";
 taxFeild.textContent = "Tax: ";
 Total.textContent = "Total with Tax: ";
}
 
function Calculate()
  {
   
   for(var i =0 ;i< checks.length;i++)
     {
       if(checks[i].checked)
         {
           count+=parseFloat(checks[i].value);
         }
     }
    ItemTotal.textContent += count;
    taxFeild.textContent += (parseFloat(tax*count).toFixed(2));
    Total.textContent += ((tax*count) + count).toFixed(2);
  }

    btn.addEventListener('click',Calculate);
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 
  
</head>
<body>

<h2 class="first-heading">Assignment 1</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
     <div id="checkBoxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'>Fried Chicken ($7.99)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='9.99'> Fried Halibut ($9.99)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='7.99'> Hamburger ($7.99)<br>  
        <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='12.99'> Grilled salmon($12.99)<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="items" value='5.99'> Side salad ($5.99)<br>      
 
   <!-- NOTICE THE ONBLUR -->
        <button id="btn" onblur="resetCalc();">Calculate</button>  

    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column" >
     
    <div id="Sums">
            <p id="ItemTotal"> Item Total: </p>
            <p id="Tax"> Tax: </p>
            <p id="TotalWithTax">Total with Tax: </p>       
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
<script src="java.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I deleted my comment when yours went away. I was trying to figure out how everyone was getting the "run code snippet" in their answers... I finally figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be plus sign when asigning content. Just replace += with = and it should work

```
    ItemTotal.textContent = count;
    taxFeild.textContent = (parseFloat(tax*count).toFixed(2));
    Total.textContent = ((tax*count) + count).toFixed(2);
```

And place captions in span like this:

```
<p> Item Total:<span id="ItemTotal"></span> </p>
<p> Tax: <span id="Tax"></span></p>
<p>Total with Tax: <span id="TotalWithTax"></span></p>
```

Comment: He is using the concatenation because his <p> tags includes the text and he must concatenate the values. @Certain Performance provided the proper semantic support to allow for better interaction. As do you :)

Comment: I am just too lazy to read the whole answer provided by CertainPerformance so I appear wrote it again in simpler way ;)

Comment: I gave you an upvote either way :) I find I often post an answer while someone else is posting an answer. And they can be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `count = 0;` on the first line of `function Calculate() { .... }` so it will gives you a new total every time your list changes.

To update the field and keep the content intact.

```js
const taxValue = tax * count;
total = taxValue + count;

ItemTotal.innerText = "Item Total:" + count;
taxFeild.innerText = "Tax:" + (parseFloat(taxValue).toFixed(2));
Total.innerText = "Total with Tax:" + (parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
```